# Dataframe to slice column content by searching sub-string

Tags: python, dataframe

A dataframe below, and I want to get the first "i" and a letter before it.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ["Diya.K","Kate.N","Ali.T","Beatriz.C","Andy.W","Gabriel.P","Peter.V"], 
'Units sold' : [48,58,20,41,21,14,22]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thinking to use Find and slicing, so had below 2 tries but neither worked:

```
df['where_i'] = df['Name'].str.find('i')
df['a_letter_before_and_i'] = df['Name'].str[df['where_i'] - 1 : df['where_i'] + 1]

where_i = df['Name'].str.find('i')
df['a_letter_before_and_i'] = df['Name'].str[where_i - 1 : where_i + 1]
```

How can I slice it by searching the key-word?

[image]

Comment: Why is there no result in the `wanted` column for the `Name` `"Diya.K"` ?

Comment: @AMC, thank you for pointing out. :)

Comment: Can you share the tables as actual text? See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: @AMC, they are outputs of the "print" from the 2 tries' snippets. I made them screenshot together with codes just for better illustration.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the code you tried, Pandas actually offers a string slicing method: [`pandas.Series.str.slice()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html#pandas.Series.str.slice). Unfortunately, it would be a bit awkward to use here.

Using regex, however, leads to a nice, simple solution:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ["Diya.K", "Kate.N", "Ali.T", "Beatriz.C", "Andy.W", "Gabriel.P", "Peter.V"],
        'Units sold': [48, 58, 20, 41, 21, 14, 22]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

letter_re = r"(.i)"

df["sub_slice"] = df["Name"].str.extract(letter_re, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Name  Units sold sub_slice
0     Diya.K          48        Di
1     Kate.N          58       NaN
2      Ali.T          20        li
3  Beatriz.C          41        ri
4     Andy.W          21       NaN
5  Gabriel.P          14        ri
6    Peter.V          22       NaN
```

Comment: thank you for the continuous follow-up! would you mind I choose another for the answer, which workable, came earlier and also straight forward?

Comment: @MarkK Which one are you referring to? I looked quickly at a few answers but they seemed unidiomatic and overly complex, which is why I shared this solution.

Comment: @MarkK The `NaN` are perfectly normal, it’s the idiomatic way of indicating a missing value.

Comment: @MarkK On second glance, I’m curious about the performance of their solution, especially since `str.find()` is called 3 times for each value. I’ll benchmark the solutions tomorrow, and include a refactored version of the loop + string slicing method which should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a small regex checking function and `apply` it to your column.

For instance:

```py
import re

def get_matches(regex, string):
    matches = re.search(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)

    if matches:
       return matches.group()

    return None
```

```
df['Name'].apply(lambda elt : get_matches('.i', elt))
```

would then return

```
0      Di
1    None
2      li
3      ri
4    None
5      ri
6    None
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: `if len(matches)==0:` can be simplified to `if not matches:`.

Comment: Also, why use `re.findall()` if you only ever care about the first result? Isn’t that what `re.search()` is for?

Comment: thanks @AMC for the valid comments. Amended the answer

Answer (score 0):

What you want is ambiguous because first name `Diya` should also give `Di`
 but based on my understanding below is the code.

```
df['where'] = df['Name'].map(lambda name: name[ name.find('i') -1 : name.find('i') + 1 ] if name.find('i') != -1 else ''   )

print(df)
    Name    Units sold  where
 0  Diya.K      48      Di
 1  Kate.N      58  
 2  Ali.T       20      li
 3  Beatriz.C   41      ri
 4  Andy.W      21  
 5  Gabriel.P   14      ri
 6  Peter.V     22
```

Comment: Does `df['where'][i]` not produce a warning? The proper way of indexing like that is using `loc` and `iloc`. I don't think you need to create the column beforehand, either.

Comment: No, it didn't give any warnings, I think it is because of the way dataFrame was created. Yeah, you are right, there was no need to create column beforehand. I have made changes to my code.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh, thank you for the help, and sharing! it works! would you mind I choose AMC's for the answer?